# Install packages globally in Amplify, instead of in build each time

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, aws-amplify

I am looking for a way where I can install and use the packages globally, currently, we install packages in amplify.yml for each build. I want to get rid of installing each time the pipeline runs.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!